# Matrix transformations and eigenvalues

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

I have a positive definite matrix $X$ of order $m$. We know that $det(X)=\prod_{i=1}^m \lambda_i$ and $tr(X)=\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i$, where $\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_m$ are the $m$ eigenvalues of $X$.

I need to work out the following expression $\log\{det(X)\}=\sum_{i=1}^m\log(\lambda_i)$. Playing a little bit I "found out" that if I have a function $g$ and I apply it componentwise to the elements of $X$, for brevity I will denote the trasformed matrix by $X_g$, then $tr(X_g)=\sum_{i=1}^m g(\lambda_i)$.

I have the following questions:

1) Is the last relation true? At least as long as it is possible to apply the function $g$ componentwise to the elements of $X$?

2) The first question is just for curiosity because, unfortunately, my matrix $X$ may have negative entries, so I cannot apply the logarithm componentwise. Thus, I was wondering whether there exist some viable/nice way to obtain an expression for $\log\{det(X)\}$.

Cheers

Comment: 2) Just take $\log$ on both sides of the equation $det(X) = \prod \lambda_i$ that you wrote above! You might want to do a quick revision of the definition of $\log$ :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Well, if I understand correctly you are just saying that I have already the answer, i.e., $\log\{det(X)\}=\sum_i\log\lambda_i$. However, the problem is that I need to use this result to develop further calculations and an expression containing the sum of the diagonal elements of some transformation of $X$ would be great. In other words, an expression containg the eigenvalues is useless to me, I need one involving the entries of the matrix $X$ (or tranformed entries).

Answer (score 0):

No, the desired relation does not hold. Consider $g(x) = e^x$, and take
$$
X = \pmatrix{2&1\\1&2}
$$
Then $tr(X_g) = 2e^2 \neq e^3 + e^1$.

If $g$ is of the form $g(x) = ax+b$, then your result does hold.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did not notice this (indeed, as I was saying before, I obtained the "result" just playing with the pc). After some thinking, maybe the right move is to seek for some transformation of X such that its trace is equal to the sum of the logarithm of the eigenvalues of $X$. Do you have any hints?

Comment: You could take the so-called "matrix logarithm", which can be defined in terms of the Taylor series of $\log(x)$ centered at $x = 1$.

Comment: Super! I came to your solution from a different path. To elaborate a bit on, I have expanded $\log\{det(X)\}=\sum_i\log\lambda_i=\sum_i \lambda_i-1-(\lambda_i-1)^2/2+(\lambda_i-1)^3/3+\cdots$. 

Now, if I consider the approximation $\sum_i \lambda_i-1-(\lambda_i-1)^2/2$, then, by using your first reply, the trace of $(X-I)-(X-I)(X-I)/2$ is equal to $\sum_i \lambda_i-1-(\lambda_i-1)^2/2$. However, I was wondering what would be the error in the approximation? $O(max\{(\lambda_i-1)^3\})$? If so, I am puzzled.

Comment: The idea is that we can consider the *infinite* matrix sum
$$
\log(X) = (X-I) - \frac 12 (X-I)^2 + \frac 13 (X-I)^3 - \cdots
$$
And, while this sum itself will not *always* converge, it can be adapted to give us a $\log(X)$ for any $X$ with the appropriate manipulation.

Comment: Thank you! I got the idea, however this approximation is not suitable for my purposes because the error is, roughy speaking, "too big" (I did also some simulations to see how many terms should I take. The results are a nightmare, no matter the number of terms).